# Solving inequality with 2 variables $a^2-b^2+ab > 0$

Tags: inequality

I have no idea how to solve this equation. I tried treating $b$ as constant value and then solving quadratic equation, but got stuck.
$$a^2-b^2+ab > 0$$

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: some real numbers

Comment: Do you want the range of values of $a$ or $b$ or something else? You can try writing writing the given expression as $(a + b)^2 - 2b^2 - ab > 0$

Comment: Treating $b$ as a constant and solving for $a$ is a possible approach. *Where* did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as $$(a+\frac b2)^2-\frac {5b^2}4\gt 0$$ or $$(2a+b)^2\gt5b^2$$Now you don't give much information about what kind of things $a$ and $b$ are, but this form may help you to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

dividing by $ab>0$ we get
$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{b}{a}+1>0$$ now set $t=\frac{a}{b}$
if $ab<0$ then we get
$$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{b}{a}+1<0$$
if $ab=0$ then we get $a^2>0$ if $b=0$ and $-b^2>0$ which is impossible, if $a=0$